# Django: implementing JOIN using Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, join, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a Q&A type of site built in Django with the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    details = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question_id = IntegerField()
    details = models.TextField()
```

I need to display a specific question together with its answers. Normally I'd need 2 queries to do that:

```
Question.objects.get(id=1)
Answer.objects.get(question_id=1)[:10]
```

I'm hoping to retrieve everything using one query. In MySQL it'd be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Question JOIN Answer ON Question.id=Answer.question_id
WHERE Question.id=1
LIMIT 10
```

Is there anyway I could do this through Django's ORM?
Would `extra()` help in this case?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is exactly what [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) does. The only gotcha is that 
you have to start with the Answer model, rather than Question, but the 
result is the same:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=1).select_related()
```

Now each answer object has a pre-fetched 'question' attribute, and 
accessing it won't hit the db again.

Comment: Thanks, what if we need name of foreign key on related table, suppose table A is related to B and B is related to C. (all tables only have "name" and "id"). we want join that every entry of A shown side by related C table object.

Comment: How can this work if `question_id` is just an integer, and `Answer` does not provide a `models.ForeignKey` field to `Question`?

Answer (score 48):

Consider using `models.ForeignKey(Question)` instead of `question_id = IntegerField()`.

This is the optimal (more relational) way to express the relationship between Questions and Answers you are trying to portray.

This way you can simply call `Answers.objects.filter(question_id=<id>)` and get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Using a `ForeignKey` is indeed the right way to go, but the query call offered in this answer only returns `Answer` objects, while the question was how to get the `Question` and `Answer` objects in one query.

Answer (score 15):

```
    class Question(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
      details = models.TextField()

    class Answer(models.Model):
      question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
      details = models.TextField()

    id = <whatever_id>    
    answers = Question.objects.get(id=id).answer_set.all()
```

Comment: `id` is a built in function now, may not have been in 2015

Answer (score 4):

#Consider A Foreign Key Relationship Between Books And Publisher

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

eclass Book(models.Model):
 publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#Fetch Publisher Name For A Book

```
book = Book.objects.select_related('publisher').get(id=1)
book.publisher.name
```

#Fetch books which have specific publisher

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.prefetch_related('book_set').get(id=1)
books = publisher.book_set.all()
```

for more
https://kwikl3arn.com/django/JOINS