# Join over django models

Tags: django, django-models, join

I want to get the result in one list using three different models in django. How do i apply join over three models.

```
class CurrentDomainChecks(models.Model):

    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domains)
    check_type = models.ForeignKey(CheckType)
    check_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, primary_key=True)
    check_value = models.CharField(_('check value'), max_length = 2048)
    check_passed = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class DomainStatus(models.Model):

    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domains)
    domain_status_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null = True, blank = True)
    domain_status = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)

class Domains(models.Model):

    domain_name = models.CharField(_('domain name'), max_length = 255, unique = True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null = True, blank = True)
    date_last_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null = True, blank = True)
    monitoring_frequency = models.CharField(_('monitoring frequency'), max_length = 20,blank = True,null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.domain_name
```

Comment: Could you add something about the result your are expecting? Some inputdata and expected output. It will help to understand your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: implementing JOIN using Django ORM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125379/django-implementing-join-using-django-orm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you read this about JOIN ?

[Django: implementing JOIN using Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125379/django-implementing-join-using-django-orm)

Answer (score 4):

["Lookups that span relationships"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)