# Displaying columns from multiple tables in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

im new with this django database querying.

how can i translate this into a django queryset

```
SELECT prod.item_code_id, prod.name, price.SRP 
FROM inventory_product prod, inventory_pricing price 
WHERE prod.item_code_id = price.item_code_id

class Product(models.Model):
  item_code_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
  color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
  brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
  item_size = models.ForeignKey(ItemSize)

class Pricing(models.Model):
  product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  item_code = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
  SRP = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: You need to perform a JOIN which is covered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125379/django-implementing-join-using-django-orm

Comment: Or you can make raw querys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Comment: how can I make the "WHERE prod.item_code_id = price.item_code_id" work? because the link is for getting a specific item.

Comment: It is a mistake to approach Django with an SQL mindset. You have models: you should think about how to get the output you want using those models, rather than starting with an SQL query. Since you haven't posted them, though, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Please post your Models without that we won't be able to help you.

Comment: updated with models, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Roseman is right. Don't use SQL query unless you really need them.

In your example, Django ORM should be enough. It would be better if you posted you models, but it will look smth like:

```
for prod in Product.objects.all():
  price = Pricing.objects.get(item_code=prod)
  print prod.pk, prod.name, price.SRP
```