# How to use Join in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python/Django.
I have two tables
tableA

```
id(pk) Name desc   tableBID(fk)
1      ABC  testdesc  1
2      XYZ  testdes   2
```

tableB

```
id Name
1  firstName
2  Second Name
```

In Django, I have written below code

```
records = tableA.objects.all()
```

this is giving me `tableA` data but I need the `TableB` Name also.

Can anyone told me how to get the TableB name like

```
1      ABC  testdesc  1  firstName
2      XYZ  testdes   2  Second Name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: implementing JOIN using Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125379/django-implementing-join-using-django-orm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get required data with one query:

```
records = tableA.objects.values('Name', 'desc', 'tableBID__Name`)
```

`tableBID__Name` will fetch name from related TableB record.

Or to get list of objects instead of dictionaries use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select):

```
records = tableA.objects.all().select_related('tableBID')
```

Comment: records = tableA.objects.all().select_related('tableBID') this one is not working for me.. i am using python 3

Comment: @vishu after `select_related` you can access `record.tableBID.Name` without additional query.